# Pandas DatetimeIndex to dataframe

Tags: pandas

How do you change a DatetimeIndex into a simple dataframe like this:

```
        month
0  2013-07-31
1  2013-08-31
2  2013-09-30
3  2013-10-31
```

This is the DatetimeIndex:

```
DatetimeIndex(['2013-07-31', '2013-08-31', '2013-09-30', '2013-10-31',
       '2013-11-30', '2013-12-31', '2014-01-31', '2014-02-28',
       '2014-03-31', '2014-04-30', '2014-05-31', '2014-06-30'],
        dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')
```

Thank you.

Comment: `pd.DataFrame(your_dt_index, columns=['month'])`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Code below should work:

```
# Import libraries
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import datetime as dt

# Create dataframe
df = pd.DataFrame(pd.DatetimeIndex(['2013-07-31', '2013-08-31', '2013-09-30', '2013-10-31',
       '2013-11-30', '2013-12-31', '2014-01-31', '2014-02-28',
       '2014-03-31', '2014-04-30', '2014-05-31', '2014-06-30'],
        dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M'), columns=['month'])
df.head(2)
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Use `DataFrame` contructor:

```
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(['2013-07-31', '2013-08-31', '2013-09-30', '2013-10-31',
       '2013-11-30', '2013-12-31', '2014-01-31', '2014-02-28',
       '2014-03-31', '2014-04-30', '2014-05-31', '2014-06-30'],
        dtype='datetime64[ns]', freq='M')

df = pd.DataFrame({'month':idx})
#alternative 
#df = pd.DataFrame({'month':df1.index})
print (df)
        month
0  2013-07-31
1  2013-08-31
2  2013-09-30
3  2013-10-31
4  2013-11-30
5  2013-12-31
6  2014-01-31
7  2014-02-28
8  2014-03-31
9  2014-04-30
10 2014-05-31
11 2014-06-30
```